# Footnote hang, & adding vertical space around footrule

Tags: spacing, indentation, footnotes

1. How do I make the footnote hang on a new line? ie have "2012 )." align with the beginning of "Susan" instead of "1".
2. How can I increase the vertical space above and below the footnote line? Can I make this a flexi space?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Scale=1.0,Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional},Ligatures=TeX]{Minion Pro}
\newcommand\liningnumbers{\addfontfeature{Numbers=Lining}}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{*.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{\hspace*{0em}\hb@xt@2em{\@thefnmark\hss}#1}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\headerfontsize}{\fontsize{8pt}{10pt}\selectfont \liningnumbers} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}        
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\headerfontsize\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} 
\headheight=10pt
\headsep=50pt  
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
Sentence with footnote.\footcite{mcclary}
\end{document}
```

Current Output:
[image: Current output]

Comment: The answer to 1 is already in [egreg's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133185/27635) to your previous question

Comment: @karlkoeller Ah, so it is. Amended accordingly.

Comment: Also your code is not compilable... Where does `\headerfontsize` come from?

Comment: @karlkoeller I am using a child documentclass based off {article}. It uses {fancyhdr} and a few other packages.

Comment: This MWE will produce error messages.  Move `\addbibresource` to after `\usepackage{biblatex}` (which defines the command); and move `\renewcommand{\headerfontsize}` to before its use in `\fancyfoot[C]` and make it a `\newcommand`.  And remove the redefinition of `\@makefntext` and use `\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}` as suggested.

Comment: Rearranging \fancyfoot[C] worked and properly realigned the page number. Removing \@makefntext puts the footnote numbers back to superscript, which is what I don't want. However, placing the {footmisc} got the hanging to work properly. If I delete \@makefntext, is there a way I can incorporate those settings into, say, {footmisc}?

Answer (score 4):

You ask:

> 1. How do I make the footnote hang on a new line? ie have "2012 )." align with the beginning of "Susan" instead of "1".
> 2. How can I increase the vertical space above and below the footnote line? Can I make this a flexi space?

1. To get "hanging" footnotes, you could load the `footmisc` package with the `hang` option:

   ```
   \usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
   ```
2. I assume that by "footnote line" you mean the short line that separates the main text block from the footnote material; this line is frequently called the footnote rule, or footrule for short. One way to change the space between the last line of the text block and the footnote separator line is to load the `geometry` package and set the desired space in the `footnotesep` option. You don't specify how large this space should be; if it were, say, `2\baselineskip`, you could load the geometry package like this:

   ```
   \usepackage[footnotesep=2\baselineskip]{geometry}
   ```

   I would recommend leaving the default amount of vertical separation between the footnote rule and the footnote material itself unchanged. However, if you must, you can change the space left blank above each footnote (including the first one in the footnote block) by doing a `\renewcommand` on the parameter `\footnotesep`; its default height is `6.65pt` if the main document font size is `10pt`, and slightly more if you're working with `11pt` or `12pt` as the main document font size. E.g., you could issue the command `\renewcommand{\footnotesep}{1\baselineskip}`. Note that this parameter has a backslash, whereas the similar-looking option to the `geometry` package does not.

   I'm not quite sure what you mean by "flexispace". In case you mean that the footnote material should always be at the very bottom of the page -- which, in the example above, is equivalent to saying that the footnotesep amount should be anywhere from 2.00 to 2.99 `\baselineskip` -- use the option `bottom` when loading the `footmisc` package.

The following is a minimal working example that illustrates the operation of the two suggested settings. The lower part of the resulting first page looks like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hang,bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage[footnotesep=2\baselineskip,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

Some thoughts.\footnote{\lipsum*[2]}

\lipsum[3-10] % fill up remainder of page and then some
\end{document}
```

Comment: The [hang] command fails to have effect despite the correct package being used—What further information do you need in order to help me? The [footnotesep] command has worked as I had hoped. You recommend not changing space after the footrule, but I do wish to tweak it slightly; how can this be achieved?

Comment: I've also just noticed that the {geometry} settings are knocking the page number off centre.

Comment: @Αναξ - please be (much!) more specific as to what's going on in your particular document. Comments such as "fails to have effect" simply aren't great diagnostic tools, I'm afraid. If you're not using the `article` document class, please state which class it is that you use. And, are you maybe loading other packages that affect the positioning of items such as page numbers?

Comment: @Αναξ - I've added an explanation of how one might change the vertical spacing *above* a footnote -- including that between the footrule and the first footnote of the footnote block.

Comment: @Nico I have explored by files a bit more (I am brand new to LaTeX, so your patience is appreciated). I am using a customised document class created by another person. It that uses the {article} class and uses the following packages: {setspace},{fancyhdr},{amssymb},{amsmath},{enumerate},{fullpage},{fontspec},{siunitx},{biblatex},{hyperref}. I don't know what each does, so I have listed all. Would it be better if I contact you privately with the files I'm working with?

Comment: @Αναξ - the `geometry` and `fullpage` packages shouldn't be used simultaneously. Can you comment out the `\usepackage{fullpage}` statement in your custom document class? Separately, there may be some options going along with `fancyhdr` that influence the positioning of the page number.

Comment: According to § 12.5 (Footnote parameters) of the unofficial LaTeX manual (`texdoc latex2e`), `\footnotesep` is not 0pt and in fact varies depending on which font size you are using.  (This recently came up in another question I answered.)

Comment: @Mico When I comment out \usepackage{fullpage} and use your suggest {footmisc} command then re-compile; my margins increase, the page number is properly centred, and footnote text is still not hanging. When I add the {geometry} command you suggest, the page number goes off centre but the margins go back to 1in as desired. I will update my original quesiton to show which I understand to be used by the {fancyhdr} package.

Comment: @jon - thanks for pointing out that the default height and depth of `\footnotesep` is not `0` but correspond to the height and depth of a `\strut` (in footnotesize mode). I'll correct my write-up accordingly.

Comment: @Αναξ - OK, I think I've solved all (well, most of the...) problems. First, I fixed your MWE to make it actually compilable. Second, I rearranged the instructions in the preamble so that the fancypage matter comes *last*. With these changes, if you now insert the instructions I provided in my answer (i.e., loading the `footmisc` and `geometry` packages, and redefining `footnotesep`) between the redefinition of `\@makefntext` and the fancypage stuff, you should be in business.

Comment: @Mico Ok, the only problem is that some of those packages are already loaded in the document class, and I don't know which commands are associated with the packages you have suggested I rearrange. The document class I am using is [nzlaw](https://github.com/klapaukh/nzlaw/blob/master/nzlaw.cls)

Comment: @Mico & al. I'm quite certain that I have implemented your advice but I'm obviously missing something. I have uploaded the files that I am using and an example of the result so that you might be able to see things I can't. Here is code for [test document](http://dumptext.com/59nVPOGS#), [nzlaw class (modified)](http://dumptext.com/i2uDdsjL), and an [image of current output](http://i41.tinypic.com/maxm47.png) ignoring the fact there is no .bib loaded or citations to the .bib.