# Add vertical space around footnote rule and between footnotes in reledmac

Tags: spacing, footnotes, reledmac

I've tried some of the usual methods (such as [changing footnotestep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133266/footnote-hang-adding-vertical-space-around-footrule) and [redefining footnoterule](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124547/distance-between-footnote-and-the-line-above-it)), but they don't seem to work with reledmac. If possible, I'd like to change (1) the space above and below the footnote rule of each series of critical notes, and (2) the space between footnotes.

**Edit:** `\Xafterrule[]{}` and `\Xbeforenotes[]{}` are the answer to my first question, but `\Xafternote[]{}` doesn't work as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia,fontspec,xunicode}
\setmainlanguage{latin}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\Xbeforenotes[A]{10pt}  % adds space above footnote rule
\Xafterrule[A]{10pt}  % adds space after the rule
\Xafternote[A]{10pt}  % does NOT add space in between notes
\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\edtext{Lorem}{
  \Afootnote{A critical note}  % space between this note and the rule, and above the rule
  \Bfootnote{Critical note in series B}}
\edtext{ipsum}{
  \Afootnote{Another critical note}  % space between this and the first Afootnote
  \Bfootnote{Other critical note in series B}}
\lipsum*[1-6]
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe Xafterrule[]{} does the job. It adds space between the rule and the note. Sorry, but I can't tell you how to add space between Afootnote and Bfootnote.

Comment: `\Xafternote` means for the *horizontal* space added at the end of an individual paragraphed note (it is documented on 6.10.1 > 6.10 is "Options for paragraphed footnotes"). So it can't be the vertical space between footnote series. If you want to control the vertical space vertical between two normal footnote, please open an issue. It is not yet possible in reledmac 2.6.0. But it should be easy to implement it.

Comment: ps : the footnote mechanism of reledmac is different to the standard footnotes mechanism. In general the hacks for the standard footnote mechanism can't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. So you must do that:

- insert vertical space at the begining of any footnotes.
- consequently, do not insert space after the rule.

So

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia,fontspec,xunicode}
\setmainlanguage{latin}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\Xparindent
\Xbeforenotes[B]{10pt}  % adds space above footnote rule
\Xafterrule[A]{0pt}  % n
\Xbhooknote[A]{\vskip 10pt\noindent} 
\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\edtext{Lorem}{
  \Afootnote{A critical note}  % space between this note and the rule, and above the rule
  \Bfootnote{Critical note in series B}}
\edtext{ipsum}{
  \Afootnote{Another critical note}  % space between this and the first Afootnote
  \Bfootnote{Other critical note in series B}}
\lipsum*[1-6]
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm trying to solve the same problem for familiar foot notes in reledmac, how are the command in this case? Just using `\beforenotesX[B]{10pt}` doesn't work, I get "Undefined control sequence. \beforenotesX   [B]"

Comment: which version of reledmac do you use ? no problem in my computer. please also provide MWE

Comment: A sorry, it was `ledmac` not `reledmac`. `\parindentX[B]` resp. `\hangindentX[B]{1cm}` in my case works now and `\beforenotesX` as well.