# Vertical space between footnotes

Tags: footnotes, reledmac, octavo

I'm trying to find an automatic way to add some space between footnotes. I'm now adding a `\smallskip` after each footnote. It solves the issue, but non elegantly. I'm using reledmac. See below for my comments on why the solution proposed does not work in my example, and I updated the MWE.

```
\documentclass[foolscap, 11pt]{octavo}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{reledmac}


\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}

\bhooknoteX[A]{\vskip1\baselineskip\noindent}
\afterruleX[A]{-1\baselineskip}


%To have critical footnotes before familiar footnotes
\fnpos{critical-familiar}
\Xbeforenotes[A]{1.8em}
\beforenotesX[A]{1.8em}
\beforenotesX[B]{1.8em}
\Xafterrule[A]{7pt}
\afterruleX[A]{7pt}
\afterruleX[B]{7pt}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\setdefaultlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}



\usepackage[style=verbose-trad3, doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,eprint=false]{biblatex}

\begin{document}
\section{First}


This is normal text with a footnote of type A. \footnoteA{\textsc{Title 1} \ Please bring me up! \blindtext[1]} \blindtext[1] And this is critical text:\footnoteA{\textsc{Title 1} \ Please bring me up! \blindtext[1]}

\beginnumbering
\pstart

\begin{quote}
This is a critical text with critical \edtext{\textit{footnotes}} { \Afootnote[nonum, nosep]{\blindtext[1] }}. And \edtext{\textit{again}}{ \Afootnote[nonum, nosep]{This is a footnote }} footnotes.
\end{quote}
\pend
\endnumbering
And this is again \footnoteA{\textsc{Title 1} \ Please bring me up! \blindtext[1]}  normal text.  \blindtext[2] 
This is normal text with a footnote of type A. \footnoteA{\textsc{Title 1} \ Please bring me up! \blindtext[1]} \blindtext[1] And this is critical text:\footnoteA{\textsc{Title 1} \ Please bring me up! \blindtext[1]}

\beginnumbering
\pstart

\begin{quote}
This is a critical text with critical \edtext{\textit{footnotes}} { \Afootnote[nonum, nosep]{\blindtext[1] }}. And \edtext{\textit{again}}{ \Afootnote[nonum, nosep]{This is a footnote }} footnotes.
\end{quote}
\pend
\endnumbering
And this is again \footnoteA{\textsc{Title 1} \ Please bring me up! \blindtext[1]}  normal text.  \blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Add vertical space around footnote rule and between footnotes in reledmac](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279249/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me there. Similar problem but I cannot make the solution solve my problem...  Very probable there is something I do not understand... sorry

Comment: If adding manually \smallskip at the end of each footnote work, you could, for example, do `\newcommand\myfootnoteA[1]{\footnoteA{#1\smallskip}}`

Comment: Thanks, but is there a precise point in my preamble where I should add this? Because I tried it in my MWE and strangely it produces no results.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't say what document class you're using, but assuming it's something like `article`, the spacing is determined by the length `footnotesep`, which you can change to whatever you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[marginparwidth=40pt, headsep=20pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\usepackage{reledmac}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}

\setlength{\footnotesep}{1\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
\section{First}
This is normal text with a footnote\footnote{\textsc{Title 1} \ \blindtext[1]} and another footnote.\footnote{\textsc{Title 2} \ \blindtext[1]}

\end{document}
```

EDIT (See comments): Special footnotes provided by reledmac do not use this amount, however. To my knowledge, the only way to deal with the problem is to use the package's hooks defined with `\bhooknoteX` (or `\Xbhooknote` for the critical variety) to insert some commands before each note; you can use `\vskip` to insert vertical space. However, since this will also affect the first note, to avoid having extra space before the first note on the page, you could set `\afterruleX` (`\Xafterrule`) to a negative amount to pull it back up to the rule.

```
% xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[marginparwidth=40pt, headsep=20pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\usepackage{reledmac}

\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
\bhooknoteX[A]{\vskip1\baselineskip\noindent} 
\afterruleX[A]{-1\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
\section{First}


This is normal text with a footnote of type A\footnoteA{\textsc{Title 1} \ \blindtext[1]} 
and another of type A\footnoteA{\textsc{Title 1} \ \blindtext[1]} 
and another  footnote but of type B.\footnoteB{\textsc{Title 2} \ \blindtext[1]}

\end{document}
```

[image: footnote space sample]

Comment: Thanks! It works for regular footnotes, but I'm using reledmac, and the command does not work with special reledmac types of footnotes. Please see my revised MWE. I'm using the Octavo document class but I did a few trials and the behavior does not change, so I kept the article class in the MWE.

Comment: @Haim The issue is definitely harder for `reledmac`, but I've added a suggestion that may work for you. See the edits to the answer.

Comment: +1 for the second approach, which coincides with the ["official" solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/279378/) by reledmac's maintainer :-)

Comment: Thanks! It works for the space AFTER but for some reason the \afterruleX[A]{-1\baselineskip} has no effect... It has an effect in the MWE but when I try it in my real text, then it makes no difference and I have space before the first footnote of a page... Any idea why? Should I post the complete preamble of my doc?

Comment: Try to get it as minimal as possible and still produce the undesired result, removing packages and commands in the preamble one by one until the problem goes away. That'll identify the culprit. If that doesn't point the way to the solution already, then post what's left of the preamble.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I discovered that the responsible is my command `\afterruleX[A]{7pt}'. If I comment it out, then the spacing among footnotes is fine, including the first. But I get worse problems, like the separation line ends up in the middle of the page and the layout gets messy. It seems to me that this happens only in the second page etc. when a footnote text overflows into the next page... Should I post a MWE? How? Thanks

Comment: I updated the MWE. Could not find a way to add a second one... Thanks!

Comment: @Haim, in your updated MWE you have 2 instances of `\afterruleX[A]`. On line 10, there's `\afterruleX[A]{-1\baselineskip}` from @frabjous's solution. On l. 19, there's `\afterruleX[A]{7pt}` from your own settings. The latter overrides the former, which is why you have to lose it if @frabjous's solution is to work at all. But you're right, there are problems when a `\footnoteA` breaks into the second page.

Comment: @marquinho Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @Haim I can't test your new code, because I don't have that font. But yes, I can see that using a negative amount with `\afterruleX` would cause a problem for a footnote split on to the next page. I hadn't thought of that. Maybe we can get @maïafeul 's attention?

Comment: @frabjous Sorry, I edited out the font... Thanks!

Comment: well, I guess the "problem when a footnoteA breaks into the second page" is a bug, but for now I have no time for reledmac...