# Kerning (with realscripts) not in footnotes marker

Tags: footnotes, kerning

Plz, consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{realscripts}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelfont[english]{rm}[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]{<myfont>}

\frenchspacing

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn \__realscripts_numtosup:n
  {
    \str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str {#1}
    \str_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_str
      {
        \str_if_in:nnTF {0123456789} {##1}
          {
            \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {##1}
            \if_case:w \l_tmpa_int ⁰
              \or: ¹
              \or: ²
              \or: ³
              \or: ⁴
              \or: ⁵
              \or: ⁶
              \or: ⁷
              \or: ⁸
              \or: ⁹
            \fi:
          }
          { {\addfontfeature{VerticalPosition=Superior}##1} }
      }
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__realscripts_numtosup:n { x }

\DeclareDocumentCommand \realsuperscript {m} {
  \fontspec_if_fontspec_font:TF
  {
    \fontspec_if_opentype:TF
    { \fontspec_if_feature:nTF {+sups}
      { \__realscripts_numtosup:x{#1} }
      { \fakesuperscript{#1} }
    }
    { \fontspec_if_aat_feature:nnTF {10} {1}
      { \__realscripts_numtosup:x{#1} }
      { \fakesuperscript{#1} }
    }
  }
  { \fakesuperscript{#1} }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
In text numbers: 0123456789

To be\footnote{xxx}. or not to be\footnote{xxx}: that is the question\footnote{xxx}:
Whether ‘tis nobler in the mind to suffer\footnote{xxx}
The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune\footnote{xxx},
Or to take arms against a sea of troubles\footnote{xxx},
And by opposing end them\footnote{xxx}? To die: to sleep\footnote{xxx};
No more\footnote{xxx}; and by a sleep\footnote{xxx} to say we end\footnote{xxx}
The heart-ache\footnote{xxx} and the thousand natural shocks\footnote{xxx}
That flesh is heir to, ‘tis a consummation\footnote{xxx}
Devoutly to be wish’d\footnote{xxx}. To die, to sleep\footnote{xxx};

A{\addfontfeatures{VerticalPosition=Superior}0123456789}.

A{\textsuperscript{9876543210}}.

A{\addfontfeatures{VerticalPosition=Superior}321}.

A{\textsuperscript{321}}.

\end{document}
```

The resulting .pdf in the following pic:

[image]

Obviously, I set a paroxysmal kerning between number 1 and period only for testing reasons. You'll note the kerning works with the last line of the code, but it's not applied to superscript notes marker. Why?

**Update**

I tried the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{realscripts}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelfont[english]{rm}[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]{Source Serif Pro}

\directlua {
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name = "supkern",
    type = "kern",
    data = {
      ["one.superior"] = { ["period"] =  -250 },
    },
  }
}

\frenchspacing

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn \__realscripts_numtosup:n
  {
    \str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str {#1}
    \str_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_str
      {
        \str_if_in:nnTF {0123456789} {##1}
          {
            \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {##1}
            \if_case:w \l_tmpa_int ⁰
              \or: ¹
              \or: ²
              \or: ³
              \or: ⁴
              \or: ⁵
              \or: ⁶
              \or: ⁷
              \or: ⁸
              \or: ⁹
            \fi:
          }
          { {\addfontfeature{VerticalPosition=Superior}##1} }
      }
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__realscripts_numtosup:n { x }

\DeclareDocumentCommand \realsuperscript {m} {
  \fontspec_if_fontspec_font:TF
  {
    \fontspec_if_opentype:TF
    { \fontspec_if_feature:nTF {+sups}
      { \__realscripts_numtosup:x{#1} }
      { \fakesuperscript{#1} }
    }
    { \fontspec_if_aat_feature:nnTF {10} {1}
      { \__realscripts_numtosup:x{#1} }
      { \fakesuperscript{#1} }
    }
  }
  { \fakesuperscript{#1} }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
In text numbers: 0123456789

To be\footnote{xxx}. or not to be\footnote{xxx}: that is the question\footnote{xxx}:
Whether ‘tis nobler in the mind to suffer\footnote{xxx}
The slings and arrows of outrageous fortune\footnote{xxx},
Or to take arms against a sea of troubles\footnote{xxx},
And by opposing end them\footnote{xxx}? To die: to sleep\footnote{xxx};
No more\footnote{xxx}; and by a sleep\footnote{xxx} to say we end\footnote{xxx}
The heart-ache\footnote{xxx} and the thousand natural shocks\footnote{xxx}
That flesh is heir to, ‘tis a consummation\footnote{xxx}
Devoutly to be wish’d\footnote{xxx}. To die, to sleep\footnote{xxx};

A{\addfontfeatures{VerticalPosition=Superior}0123456789}.

A{\textsuperscript{9876543210}}.

A{\addfontfeatures{VerticalPosition=Superior}321}.

A{\textsuperscript{321}}.

A{\addfontfeature{RawFeature=+sups}1.}

A{\addfontfeature{RawFeature=+supkern;+sups}1.}

\end{document}
```

but `\directlua` doesn't produce any result and the last two line unnecessary, for period is itself superscrit. What's wrong?

**Further update**

Try this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua {
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name = "supkern",
    type = "kern",
    data = {
      ["¹"] = { ["."] =  -180,
                [","] =  -180 },
    },
  }
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelfont[english]{rm}[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},RawFeature=+supkern,RawFeature=+calt]{Source Serif Pro}
\usepackage{realscripts}
\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnote}
\usepackage[bottom,hang,stable,norule]{footmisc} % perpage
\renewcommand{\footnotemargin}{0.01em}
\renewcommand{\hangfootparskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\hspace{1em}}

\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{\unpenalty{\footnotemarkfont\textsuperscript{\@thefnmark}}}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \l__realscripts_punct_found_bool
\tl_new:N \l__realscripts_footnote_text_tl
\cs_set_eq:NN \__realscripts_footnote:n \footnote
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__realscripts_footnote_with_punct:
  {
    \bool_set_false:N \l__realscripts_punct_found_bool
    \str_map_inline:nn { ., }
      {
        \token_if_eq_meaning:NNT \l_peek_token ##1
          {
            \footnotemark
            \l_peek_token
            \footnotetext { \l__realscripts_footnote_text_tl }
            \bool_set_true:N \l__realscripts_punct_found_bool
            \str_map_break:
          }
      }
    \bool_if:NTF \l__realscripts_punct_found_bool
      { \use_none:n }
      { \__realscripts_footnote:n { \l__realscripts_footnote_text_tl } }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__realscripts_footnote_with_punct:n
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__realscripts_footnote_text_tl {#1}
    \peek_after:Nw \__realscripts_footnote_with_punct:
  }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__realscripts_numtosup:n
  {
    \str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str {#1}
    \str_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_str
      {
        \str_if_in:nnTF { 0123456789 } {##1}
          {
            \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {##1}
            \if_case:w \l_tmpa_int ⁰
              \or: ¹
              \or: ²
              \or: ³
              \or: ⁴
              \or: ⁵
              \or: ⁶
              \or: ⁷
              \or: ⁸
              \or: ⁹
            \fi:
          }
          { { \addfontfeature {VerticalPosition=Superior} ##1 } }
      }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__realscripts_numtosup:n { x }
\DeclareDocumentCommand \realsuperscript { m } {
  \fontspec_if_fontspec_font:TF
  {
    \fontspec_if_opentype:TF
    { \fontspec_if_feature:nTF {+sups}
      { \__realscripts_numtosup:x{#1} }
      { \fakesuperscript{#1} }
    }
    { \fontspec_if_aat_feature:nnTF {10} {1}
      { \__realscripts_numtosup:x{#1} }
      { \fakesuperscript{#1} }
    }
  }
  { \fakesuperscript{#1} }
}
\DeclareDocumentCommand \footnote { +m }
  {
    \__realscripts_footnote_with_punct:n {#1}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

«text»\footnote{Footnote text}.

A\footnote{Footnote text}.

A\footnote{Footnote text},

A\footnote{Footnote text};

A\footnote{Footnote text}.

\end{document}
```

You'll realize that something strange happens: no footnote 1!

Comment: It would be better if you would make an example with a real font that exists also on our systems and not with a `<myfont`>. You can add special kerns with fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312154/how-to-adjust-font-features-in-luatex.

Comment: The kerning is not applied to footnote marks because the marker is wrapped in a box.  LaTeX defines `\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I updated my answer to your [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473983/lining-numbers-for-footnote) before seeing this one. For the sake of getting the right things in the right place, here's my answer reproduced.

Your kerning problem is caused by the fact that the footnote mark is set inside an `\hbox`. This destroys the kerning between 'A' and '¹'. Consider this code using my patched `\realsuperscript` macro from below:

```
A{\addfontfeatures{VerticalPosition=Superior}1}.
A{\textsuperscript{1}}.
A\footnote{1}.}
```

When we show this we get:

```
.\TU/SourceSerifPro(0)/m/n/12 A
.\TU/SourceSerifPro(1)/m/n/12 ¹
.\TU/SourceSerifPro(0)/m/n/12 .
.\glue(\spaceskip) 3.72801 plus 4.19398 minus 0.31067
.\TU/SourceSerifPro(0)/m/n/12 A
.\kern-1.68 (font)
.\TU/SourceSerifPro(0)/m/n/12 ¹
.\TU/SourceSerifPro(0)/m/n/12 .
.\glue(\spaceskip) 3.72801 plus 4.19398 minus 0.31067
.\TU/SourceSerifPro(0)/m/n/12 A
.\penalty 10000
.\hbox(9.936+0.0)x4.44, direction TLT
..\TU/SourceSerifPro(0)/m/n/12 ¹
.\insert253, natural size 12.00003; split(8.4,3.60004); float cost 20000
..\hbox(8.4+3.60004)x390.0, glue set 367.63995fil, direction TLT
...\localpar
....\localinterlinepenalty=0
....\localbrokenpenalty=0
....\localleftbox=null
....\localrightbox=null
...\hbox(8.28+0.0)x18.00003, glue set 14.30003fil, direction TLT
....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
....\hbox(8.28+0.0)x3.7, direction TLT
.....\TU/SourceSerifPro(0)/m/n/10 ¹
...\hbox(8.4+0.0)x0.0, direction TLT
....\rule(8.4+0.0)x0.0
...\TU/SourceSerifPro(0)/m/n/10 
...\penalty 10000
...\rule(0.0+3.60004)x0.0
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
.\TU/SourceSerifPro(0)/m/n/12 .
```

We can see that

1. In the first case there is a font change and no kerning is inserted.
2. In the second case there is no font change and kerning is inserted.
3. In the third case there is a `\penalty` and and then '¹' is placed inside an `\hbox` and therefore no kerning is inserted even though there is no font change.
4. I the third case the `\hbox` with the footnote mark and the final period is separated by the float material for the footnote text. Therefore any kerning between '¹' and '.' is lost.

So to work around this two things are needed:

1. Adjust the `\@makefnmark` macro (previously adjusted from the default by the `realscripts` package) to remove the penalty and not to use the `\hbox`. This could have unwanted side effects, of course :).
2. Use `A\footnotemark.\footnotetext{…}` instead of `A\footnote{…}.`

The first could be achieved by using something like:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{\unpenalty{\footnotemarkfont\textsuperscript{\@thefnmark}}}
\makeatother
```

I have had a go at redefining `\footnote` to test for punctuation and automatically deal with the second point.

### MWE

Here's a full MWE (I added some `directlua` to add kerning between '¹' and '.' and ',' as Source Sans Serif does not include this). It also shows how to patch things to make it work with the `perpage` and `stable` options of the `footmisc` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua {
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name = "supkern",
    type = "kern",
    data = {
      ["¹"] = { ["."] =  -180,
                [","] =  -180 },
      ["²"] = { ["."] =  -180,
                [","] =  -180 },
      ["³"] = { ["."] =  -180,
                [","] =  -180 },
      ["⁵"] = { ["."] =  -180,
                [","] =  -180 },
    },
  }
}
\usepackage{realscripts}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelfont[english]{rm}[Ligatures=TeX,Language=Default,Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},RawFeature=+supkern]{Source Serif Pro}
\usepackage[perpage,bottom,hang,stable,norule]{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\footnotemargin}{0.01em}
\renewcommand{\hangfootparskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\hspace{1em}}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{\unpenalty{\footnotemarkfont\textsuperscript{\@thefnmark}}}
\ifFN@perpage
  \xpatchcmd{\footnotemark}
    {\ifFN@pp@towrite
       \FN@pp@writetemp
       \FN@pp@towritefalse
     \fi}
    {}
    {}
    {}
  \xpretocmd{\@footnotetext}
    {\ifFN@pp@towrite
       \FN@pp@writetemp
       \FN@pp@towritefalse
     \fi}
    {}
    {}
  \ifFN@stablefootnote
    \xpatchcmd{\FN@sf@@footnotemark}
      {\ifFN@pp@towrite
         \FN@pp@writetemp
         \FN@pp@towritefalse
       \fi}
      {}
      {}
      {}
  \fi
\fi
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \l__realscripts_punct_found
\tl_new:N \l__realscripts_footnote_text_tl
\cs_set_eq:NN \__realscripts_footnote:n \footnote
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__realscripts_footnote_with_punct:
  {
    \bool_set_false:N \l__realscripts_punct_found
    \str_map_inline:nn { ., }
      {
        \token_if_eq_meaning:NNT \l_peek_token ##1
          {
            \footnotemark
            \l_peek_token
            \footnotetext { \l__realscripts_footnote_text_tl }
            \bool_set_true:N \l__realscripts_punct_found
            \str_map_break:
          }
      }
    \bool_if:NTF \l__realscripts_punct_found
      {
        \use_none:n
      }
      {
        \__realscripts_footnote:n { \l__realscripts_footnote_text_tl }
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__realscripts_footnote_with_punct:n
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__realscripts_footnote_text_tl {#1}
    \peek_after:Nw \__realscripts_footnote_with_punct:
  }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__realscripts_numtosup:n
  {
    \str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str {#1}
    \str_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_str
      {
        \str_if_in:nnTF {0123456789} {##1}
          {
            \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {##1}
            \if_case:w \l_tmpa_int ⁰
              \or: ¹
              \or: ²
              \or: ³
              \or: ⁴
              \or: ⁵
              \or: ⁶
              \or: ⁷
              \or: ⁸
              \or: ⁹
            \fi:
          }
          { { \addfontfeature {VerticalPosition=Superior} ##1 } }
      }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__realscripts_numtosup:n { x }
\DeclareDocumentCommand \realsuperscript { m }
  {
    \fontspec_if_fontspec_font:TF
      {
        \fontspec_if_opentype:TF
          {
            \fontspec_if_feature:nTF { +sups }
              { \__realscripts_numtosup:x {#1} }
              { \fakesuperscript {#1} }
          }
          { 
            \fontspec_if_aat_feature:nnTF {10} {1}
              { \__realscripts_numtosup:x {#1} }
              { \fakesuperscript {#1} }
          }
      }
      { \fakesuperscript {#1} }
  }
\DeclareDocumentCommand \footnote { +m }
  {
    \__realscripts_footnote_with_punct:n {#1}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test chapter}

«text»\footnote{Footnote text}.

A\footnote{Footnote text}.

A\footnote{Footnote text},

A\footnote{Footnote text};

A\footnote{Footnote text}.
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: The matter is complicated. Your code works well, however it interferes with other note management packages: for example if you use footmisc, you return to the starting situation ... no kerning

Comment: @user41063, Make sure you load `footmisc` before you redefine `@makefnmark`, as `footmisc` also redefines this.

Comment: I tried, but it does not seem to work even when first loading the packages dedicated to managing the notes as `footmisc`

Comment: @user41063, I included a redefinition of `\footnote` and also the `footmisc` package to show that it does work.

Comment: what a great work! now I make some testing... Thank you!

Comment: If my test are correct, your last code works fine with many `footmisc` options, except if you enter the option `perpage`

Comment: It works by removing the perpage option and entering directly a code like  `\makeatletter
\@newctr{footnote}[page]
\makeatother`

Comment: Full compatibility with packege `perpage` with option `\MakePerPage{footnote}`

Comment: @user41063, to make it work with `\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}`  a little more patching is required.

Comment: Plz, consider my last update!

Comment: @user41063, there were two additional problems. Using the `perpage` package causes problems (which I didn't bother to investigate, as you can use the `perpage` option of `footmisc`). And another adjustment is needed for the `stable` option of `footmisc`. Any more mystery footnote customisations? This shows the importance of providing a MWE that includes everything that is relevant. Since you are messing with the internals of footnotes, anything that affects footnotes is important.

Comment: You're right, but not always it's possible to forecast all situation. In any case, another mystery. The code doesn't work with `hyperref`, for instance with: `\usepackage[pdfencoding=unicode]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
 pdftitle={Pdftitle},
 pdfauthor={Pdfauthor},
 hidelinks
}
\usepackage{bookmark}`

Comment: It request `hyperfootnotes=false` option to work. But let me test again

Comment: Yes, hyperref also messes with footnotes.

Comment: In the next day I'll test the code in some other big files of mine. Thank you a lot for your great job and your helpfullness. Why don't you think to create a package managing these typographycal aspects of footnotes? There are no packages with this function, if not `fnpct`, which however is not very elastic (applies an equal kerning for all the superscript) and is currently also broken ...

Comment: @user41063, I think it's time to tie this question off. (Maybe mark it as answered). `hyperref` is going to be problematic and deserves a new question, which more people will see. You could use a MWE example like this: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
AVA A\href{www.example.com}{V}A
\end{document}` and ask if it is possible to preserve the automatic font kerning. I think if it is possible, it will require some kind of Lua magic that is beyond my skill. When you ask the question, link back to this one for context, but use the smaller MWE.

Comment: I'll consider a package. I've found it quite an interesting challenge to make it work. But it would need to be made a fair bit more flexible and customisable to make such a package useful. And `hyperref` is definitely a challenge that would be useful, but I have no idea how to solve the problem. Similar issues also surface just with colour: `A\textcolor{red}{V}` also destroys kerning. But you could work around that one by using `fontspec` colouring.

Comment: ok, consider this thread closed. In case, I will post other questions. Of course, a package should be flexible and compatible with many other packages. I only observe that my problem stems from the fact that, despite being a very advanced typographic composition system, LaTeX does not adequately manage the kerning built inside the font, which is certainly a flaw. Thanks again for your help