# Convert token to string in LaTeX3

Tags: expl3, strings, token-lists

While trying to answer another question on this site, I was experimenting with `\peek_after:Nw` and `\l_peek_token`.

I can set `\l_peek_token` OK, but then I want to test if this token is one of several characters, rather than just one character. (Just one character is easy and I could use `\peek_meaning:NTF`.)

I thought that I would be able to easily convert `l_peek_token` to a string and then use `\str_if_in:nnTF` for the test. But, I don't know how to do this.

I know I could use a bunch of nested `\token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF`, but I find this syntax clumsy.

How can I do this?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn \__dcp_test_punct:
  {
    % What goes here to convert \l_peek_token to the right format?
    \str_if_in:nnTF {.,} { \l_peek_token }
      { ~Punctuation~found:~ }
      { ~Punctuation~not~found~ }
    ---
    % This works, but I find the syntax clumsy.
    \token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF \l_peek_token .
      { ~Punctuation~found:~ }
      {
        \token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF \l_peek_token ,
          { ~Punctuation~found:~ }
          { ~Punctuation~not~found~ }
      }
  }
\cs_new:Nn \__dcp_test_punct:n
  {
    \peek_after:Nw \__dcp_test_punct:
  }
\DeclareDocumentCommand {\testpunct} { m }
  {
    \__dcp_test_punct:n {#1}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\testpunct{A}.

\testpunct{A},

\testpunct{A}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\l_peek_token` is defined with `\futurelet`, so in case the next token is a character `\l_peek_token` is an “implicit character”, which is not the same as a character; in particular, it is not expandable.

Comment: @egreg, does this mean that it's basically impossible to use the kind of construction I have in `\__dcp_test_punct:`? (I have now come up with a slightly different way of doing it, that I'm just as happy with.)

Comment: You have to do a loop over the characters to check. Be careful that neither `\str_if_in:nnTF` nor `\peek_after:Nw` are expandable, so `\cs_new_protected:Nn` should be used.

Comment: @egreg, does that mean that in my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474173/87678), I should use `\cs_new_protected:Nn \__realscripts_footnote_with_punct:` and `\cs_new_protected:Nn \__realscripts_footnote_with_punct:n`?

Comment: Yes: any function that calls unexpandable functions should be `_protected`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Further thinking along with @egreg's comments have led me to do things in a slightly different way and use an inline map. It's not quite as compact as I might have hoped to achieve with `\str_if_in:nnTF`, but at least it doesn't involve nested boolean checks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\bool_new:N \l__dcp_punct_found_bool
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__dcp_test_punct:
  {
    \bool_set_false:N \l__dcp_punct_found_bool
    \str_map_inline:nn { .,:;!? }
      {
        \token_if_eq_meaning:NNT \l_peek_token ##1
          {
            ~Punctuation~found:~
            \bool_set_true:N \l__dcp_punct_found_bool
            \str_map_break:
          }
      }
    \bool_if:NF \l__dcp_punct_found_bool
      { ~Punctuation~not~found~ }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__dcp_test_punct:n
  {
    \peek_after:Nw \__dcp_test_punct:
  }
\DeclareDocumentCommand {\testpunct} { +m }
  {
    \__dcp_test_punct:n {#1}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\testpunct{A}.

\testpunct{A},

\testpunct{A}:

\testpunct{A};

\testpunct{A}!

\testpunct{A}?

\testpunct{A}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I was just playing around with `\futurelet`.  The idea of turning the resulting implicit-character token (related: [A Question About \futurelet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474451/a-question-about-futurelet)) into something explicit with the use of `\meaning` was suggested to me by Christian Tellechea.

Christian actually provided (under separate cover) a macro `\implicittomacro` that converts catcode 11/12 implicit-character tokens into a macro.  You can go to my answer [A Question About \futurelet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474451/a-question-about-futurelet/474585#474585), to see his macro.

My goal was to be able to use the features of the `listofitems` package to search the implicit token's value for multiple punctuation values all at once, as detailed in the specification `\setsepchar{.||,||:||;||!||?}`.  Success!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,xcolor}
\newcommand\testpunct[1]{#1\futurelet\xfl\pdecide}
\def\pdecide{\bgroup\tiny\color{cyan}%
  \edef\ximp{\meaning\xfl}%
  \edef\tmp{\detokenize{the character }}%
  \expandafter\setsepchar\expandafter{\tmp}%
  \readlist\mylist{\ximp}%
  \ifnum\listlen\mylist[]<2\relax (Non catcode=12 follows)\else%
    \setsepchar{.||,||:||;||!||?}%
    \itemtomacro\mylist[2]\thecharacter%
    \readlist*\mychar{\thecharacter}%
    \ifnum\listlen\mychar[]=1\relax (Non-punctuation character follows \mychar[1])\else%
      (This Punctuation found: \mycharsep[1])%
    \fi%
  \fi%
\egroup}
\begin{document}
\testpunct{A}\relax

\testpunct{A}B

\testpunct{A}@

\testpunct{A}.

\testpunct{A},

\testpunct{A}:

\testpunct{A};

\testpunct{A}!

\testpunct{A}?

\testpunct{A}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Haha. This is exactly why `expl3` is so good for people like me :). It turns the incomprehensible into something that I can understand.

Comment: @DavidPurton Haha indeed.  I understood you were asking vis-a-vis `expl3`.  But I was just having fun and ended up on  a quest to digest implicit tokens.  Please forgive my presumptuousness,

Comment: @DavidPurton But, just to put into context, when you have, for example, `\let\z=.`, it is awful hard to actually deduce, after the fact, what is in \z.  But `\meaning\z` gives the response `the character .` except everything in that string is catcode 12 (even the alphabetic letters).  So the trick (and technique here) is to issue a `\meaning` and save and parse the output of it to recapture what `\z` actually was.

Comment: Oh, no worries, I just despair of ever getting to the point of understanding enough to come up with something like that. And even when I see it, it's still hard to follow! At least `expl3` hides away a lot of stuff from me