# Kerning numbers of endnotes

Tags: kerning, endnotes

The management of kerning appears in LaTeX not so effective in the case of note numbers. A magnificent solution for footnotes has been provided by David Purton in this thread:

[Lining numbers for footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473983/lining-numbers-for-footnote)

Now, since I have to produce an article with the notes at the end of the text, that solution does not work. Is there a way to re-adapt the code produced by David Purton to endnotes?

I enclose a MWE of the basic endnotes code, obviously without kerning.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelfont[english]{rm}[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers=Proportional,OldStyle},RawFeature=+calt]{Source Serif Pro}

\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto{\theendnotes}{%
\renewcommand{\makeenmark}{\textsuperscript{\theenmark}\enspace}%
}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\begin{document}

text text «text»\footnote{Footnote text.}.

text text «text»\footnote{Footnote text.}.

text text «text»\footnote{Footnote text.}.

text text «text»\footnote{Footnote text.}.

text text «text»\footnote{Footnote text.}.

text text «text»\footnote{Footnote text.}.

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

Thank you

**ADDENDUM**

A more complex test, with superscript footnotes numbers, but for bibliography:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{jobname.bib}
@book{ stegmuller:1976,
  author         = "Stegmüller, Wolfgang",
  title          = "The Structure and Dynamics of Theories",
  publisher  = "Springer",
  location   = "New-York Heidelberg Berlin",
  year       = "1976",
}
\end{filecontents*}{jobname.bib}

    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelfont[english]{rm}[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},RawFeature=+supkern,RawFeature=+calt]{Source Serif Pro}

\usepackage{xpatch}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto{\theendnotes}{%
  \renewcommand{\makeenmark}{\textsuperscript{\theenmark}\enspace}%
}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\usepackage{realscripts}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__realscripts_numtosup:n
  {
    \str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str {#1}
    \str_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_str
      {
        \str_if_in:nnTF {0123456789} {##1}
          {
            \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {##1}
            \if_case:w \l_tmpa_int ⁰
              \or: ¹
              \or: ²
              \or: ³
              \or: ⁴
              \or: ⁵
              \or: ⁶
              \or: ⁷
              \or: ⁸
              \or: ⁹
            \fi:
          }
          { { \addfontfeature {VerticalPosition=Superior} ##1 } }
      }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__realscripts_numtosup:n { x }
\DeclareDocumentCommand \realsuperscript { m }
  {
    \fontspec_if_fontspec_font:TF
      {
        \fontspec_if_opentype:TF
          {
            \fontspec_if_feature:nTF { +sups }
              { \__realscripts_numtosup:x {#1} }
              { \fakesuperscript {#1} }
          }
          {
            \fontspec_if_aat_feature:nnTF {10} {1}
              { \__realscripts_numtosup:x {#1} }
              { \fakesuperscript {#1} }
          }
      }
      { \fakesuperscript {#1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%% BIBLIOGRAPHY
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=philosophy-verbose,scauthors=all,%
lowscauthors=true,giveninits,classical=true,volnumformat=strings,%
volumeformat=romansc,sorting=nyt,commacit=true,citepages=omit,%
editionformat=superscript,indexing]%
{biblatex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\addbibresource{jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

Text\footnote{Footnote text} more «text»\footcite[220]{stegmuller:1976}. Further text

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\linespread{0.9}
\theendnotes

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

Does \footcite have a different approach to superscript numbers?

**LAST UPDATE**

When I try to compile this source:

```
  \begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{ stegmuller:1976,
  author     = "Stegmüller, Wolfgang",
  title      = "The Structure and Dynamics of Theories",
  publisher  = "Springer",
  location   = "New-York Heidelberg Berlin",
  year       = "1976",
  edition    = "2",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\directlua {
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name = "supkern",
    type = "kern",
    data = {
      ["¹"] = { ["."] =  -180,
                [","] =  -180 },
      ["²"] = { ["."] =  -180,
                [","] =  -180 },
      ["³"] = { ["."] =  -180,
                [","] =  -180 },
      ["⁴"] = { ["."] =  -180,
                [","] =  -180 },
    },
  }
}

\usepackage{realscripts}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\babelfont[english]{rm}[Ligatures=TeX,Language=Default,Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},RawFeature=+supkern]{Source Serif Pro}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__realscripts_numtosup:n
  {
    \str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str {#1}
    \str_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_str
      {
        \str_if_in:nnTF {0123456789} {##1}
          {
            \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {##1}
            \if_case:w \l_tmpa_int ⁰
              \or: ¹
              \or: ²
              \or: ³
              \or: ⁴
              \or: ⁵
              \or: ⁶
              \or: ⁷
              \or: ⁸
              \or: ⁹
            \fi:
          }
          { { \addfontfeature {VerticalPosition=Superior} ##1 } }
      }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__realscripts_numtosup:n { x }
\DeclareDocumentCommand \realsuperscript { m }
  {
    \fontspec_if_fontspec_font:TF
      {
        \fontspec_if_opentype:TF
          {
            \fontspec_if_feature:nTF { +sups }
              { \__realscripts_numtosup:x {#1} }
              { \fakesuperscript {#1} }
          }
          {
            \fontspec_if_aat_feature:nnTF {10} {1}
              { \__realscripts_numtosup:x {#1} }
              { \fakesuperscript {#1} }
          }
      }
      { \fakesuperscript {#1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto{\theendnotes}{%
  \renewcommand{\makeenmark}{\textsuperscript{\theenmark}\enspace}%
}
\makeatletter
\def\@makeenmark{\unpenalty{\footnotemarkfont\textsuperscript{\@theenmark}}}
\makeatother
\let\footnote\endnote

\usepackage[style=philosophy-verbose, scauthors=all, lowscauthors=true,
  giveninits, classical=true, volnumformat=strings, volumeformat=romansc,
  sorting=nyt, commacit=true, citepages=omit, editionformat=superscript,
  indexing]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

A\footnote{Footnote text}.

A\footnote{Footnote text},

A\footnote{Footnote text};

A\footcite[53]{stegmuller:1976}.

\theendnotes

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

1) first compilation with lualates works fine

2) bibliography compilation with biber works fine

3) new final compilation with lualates produces this error:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \l__exp_internal_tl.
<to be read again> 
1
l.17 {footcite}{}{53}{stegmuller:1976}{}}}

?
```

I realized that the error comes from `edition    = "2",`in the bibliographical record. That is the very reason for the compilation stops!

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately, it's straight forward to modify things from my previous answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474173/87678) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/473996/87678) to work with end notes.

**Note** that your last update with the example of the `edition` field in the bibliography entry reveals a weakness in my code. It assumes that the argument to `\textsuperscript` is fully expandable, but this is not necessarily the case (and isn't the case for `\mkbibsuperscript` which is used by `biblatex-philosophy` to format the `edition`). I've worked around this in the MWE below, but you will run into other problems.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{ stegmuller:1976,
  author     = "Stegmüller, Wolfgang",
  title      = "The Structure and Dynamics of Theories",
  publisher  = "Springer",
  location   = "New-York Heidelberg Berlin",
  year       = "1976",
  edition    = "2",
}
\end{filecontents}

\directlua {
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name = "supkern",
    type = "kern",
    data = {
      ["¹"] = { ["."] =  -180,
                [","] =  -180 },
      ["²"] = { ["."] =  -180,
                [","] =  -180 },
      ["³"] = { ["."] =  -180,
                [","] =  -180 },
      ["⁴"] = { ["."] =  -180,
                [","] =  -180 },
    },
  }
}

\usepackage{realscripts}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\babelfont[english]{rm}[Ligatures=TeX,Language=Default,Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle},RawFeature=+supkern]{Source Serif Pro}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__realscripts_numtosup:n
  {
    \str_set:Nn \l_tmpa_str {#1}
    \str_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_str
      {
        \str_if_in:nnTF {0123456789} {##1}
          {
            \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {##1}
            \if_case:w \l_tmpa_int ⁰
              \or: ¹
              \or: ²
              \or: ³
              \or: ⁴
              \or: ⁵
              \or: ⁶
              \or: ⁷
              \or: ⁸
              \or: ⁹
            \fi:
          }
          { { \addfontfeature {VerticalPosition=Superior} ##1 } }
      }
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__realscripts_numtosup:n { x }
\DeclareDocumentCommand \realsuperscript { m }
  {
    \fontspec_if_fontspec_font:TF
      {
        \fontspec_if_opentype:TF
          {
            \fontspec_if_feature:nTF { +sups }
            { \__realscripts_numtosup:x {#1} }
              { \fakesuperscript {#1} }
          }
          {
            \fontspec_if_aat_feature:nnTF {10} {1}
              { \__realscripts_numtosup:x {#1} }
              { \fakesuperscript {#1} }
          }
      }
      { \fakesuperscript {#1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto{\theendnotes}{%
  \renewcommand{\makeenmark}{\textsuperscript{\theenmark}\enspace}%
}
\makeatletter
\def\@makeenmark{\unpenalty{\footnotemarkfont\textsuperscript{\@theenmark}}}
\makeatother
\let\footnote\endnote

\usepackage[style=philosophy-verbose, scauthors=all, lowscauthors=true,
  giveninits, classical=true, volnumformat=strings, volumeformat=romansc,
  sorting=nyt, commacit=true, citepages=omit, editionformat=superscript,
  indexing]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\makeatletter
\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{%
  \ifinteger{#1}{%
    \ifdefstring{\bbx@editionformat}{arabic}
    {\mkbibordedition{#1}~\bibstring{edition}}
    {\ifdefstring{\bbx@editionformat}{Roman}%
      {\RN{#1}~\bibstring{edition}}%
      {\ifdefstring{\bbx@editionformat}{romansc}%
        {\textsc{\Rn{#1}}~\bibstring{edition}}%
        {\ifdefstring{\bbx@editionformat}{roman}%
          {\Rn{#1}~\bibstring{edition}}
          {\ifdefstring{\bbx@editionformat}{superscript}%
            {\textsuperscript{#1}}%
            {\optionerror{editionformat}}}}}}}{#1}}%\isdot??
\makeatother

\begin{document}

A\footnote{Footnote text}.

A\footnote{Footnote text},

A\footnote{Footnote text};

A\footcite[53]{stegmuller:1976}.

\theendnotes

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanx a lot!! I add an update for a more complex situation

Comment: @user41063, it works fine with `biblatex`. Your MWE has some errors in it and you haven't included the custom kerning between super scripts and punctuation which is not present in Source Serif Pro. I'll update my answer to show that it works.

Comment: Yes, you're right. For a copy/paste error the original code didn't work. I made some trial, your code works fine. But in the original text I'm working around I've a (for me) incomprehensible. I added a LAST UPDATE with that code. Thank you again

Comment: @user41063 one error is that you should not have jobname.bib after `\end{filecontents}`.

Comment: @user41063. That's the only error. BTW, typically we use `\jobname.bib`, rather than `jobname.bib`. This makes the temporary `bib` file have the same name as the `tex` file.

Comment: I have modified the code according to your correct remarks. Then, I went to trial and error because I didn't understand what was blocking the compilation, and finally I found. I updated the code and reported the cause of the problem: the edition number ... The MWE is now updated to show the error

Comment: @user41063, this happens because of how the edition is printed. The argument to `\textsuperscript` is not expandable. It is possible to work around this by slightly redefining the edition field format. But you will run into other problems whenever the argument to `\textsuperscript` is unexpandable.

Comment: I'll ask to 'philosophy' package author. For at present I I see no other way out

Comment: @user41063, `\mkbibsuperscript` is actually a core `biblatex` function. But this is just one example of what might end up in the argument to `\textsuperscript` that won't work. There could be all kinds of things.

Comment: I see this it's a dangerous affair. 
Unfortunately these interferences do not always make the code for the kerning of superscript numbers applicable. A small flaw in LaTeX's excellent font management

Comment: Thanx again, I'll test your last code for my purpose. Can I apply it to the old code for foot- (and not end-) note ?

Comment: @user41063, yes should be fine to do this.

Comment: Yes, tested and works fine!

Comment: I apologize for the late reply. however in these days I have tested the code in some of my files and so far I have not encountered problems.
My files are essentially relatively simple non-mathematical texts and everything seems to be going well.
I will report any problems: for the moment, thank you very much!