# Lining numbers for footnotes

Tags: luatex, footnotes, oldstylenums, liningnums

Referring to this thread: [OldStyle Numbers in Body Text Only—Lining Numbers Otherwise](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133168/oldstyle-numbers-in-body-text-only-lining-numbers-otherwise)m how can I instruct LuaLatex to use lining numbers for \textsuperscript and footnote markers if my font use by default old style numbers and hasn't super- sub-script figures built-in? Thank you

**Addendum**

This is a very basic MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelfont[english]{rm}[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]{EBGaramond}

\usepackage[perpage,bottom,hang,stable,norule]{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\footnotemargin}{0.01em}
\renewcommand{\hangfootparskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\hspace{1em}}

\begin{document}

text\textsuperscript{abdx 136}

text\footnote{footnote text}

\end{document}
```

The fact is that my font (which is a test version, not EBGaramond used for my MWE) has not superior and inferior numbers, so I can't use `realscript` package

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ, whether or not you load the `fontspec`  package, and with which options and arguments you execute `\setmainfont`.

Comment: Added a MWΕ See above

Comment: I vaguely remember that at least `garamondx` had an option for real superiors and inferiors. They might work also with your font and with EB Garamond.

Comment: but my problem is if and only if I use a font [em]without[/em] real superiors and inferiors... If 've them, there is no problem in choosing if I want to adopt the one or the other form. Moreover, for I'm using Lualatex, I think the way to set alternative forms for glyphs is very different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just manually change the relevant LaTeX macros:

There are two parts: We begin with `\textsuperscript`. It is defined by default as

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*\textsuperscript[1]{%
  \@textsuperscript{\selectfont#1}}
```

We want to use lining numbers, so we have to add `\liningnums{...}`. We can omit `\selectfont` because `\liningnums` will set the font anyway:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*\textsuperscript[1]{%
  \@textsuperscript{\liningnums{#1}}%
}
```

This changes `\textsuperscript`, but footnotes are not affected yet. The footnote marks are generated by `\@makefnmark`, which by default is defined as

```
\def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}
```

On a first glance you might assume that we could have changed `\@textsuperscript` instead of `\textsuperscript` to affect this one too, but that is not the case: The `\normalfont` would have reverted the number style to old-style numbers. So we have to add `\liningnums` *after* `\normalfont`:

```
\renewcommand\@makefnmark{%
  \hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\liningnums{\@thefnmark}}}%
}
```

Put it all together, add some `\makeatletter...\makeatother` because we used macro names with `@`, and we get

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelfont[english]{rm}[Ligatures=TeX,Numbers={Proportional,OldStyle}]{EBGaramond}

\usepackage[perpage,bottom,hang,stable,norule]{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\footnotemargin}{0.01em}
\renewcommand{\hangfootparskip}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\hspace{1em}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefnmark{%
  \hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\liningnums{\@thefnmark}}}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\textsuperscript[1]{%
  \@textsuperscript{\liningnums{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

text\textsuperscript{abdx 136}

abdx 136

text\footnote{footnote text}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfectly working. Thank you!